# Jacobian of an orthogonal transformation

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, change-of-variable

Suppose I have an integral to evaluate with respect to the column vector of $n$ variables, $x=[x_1,x_2,...x_n]^T$;

$\int f(x)dx$

And I make a change of variables to a new column vector, $y$, of length $n$, by setting $y=Ax$ where $A$ is an $(n\times n)$ orthogonal matrix. Is it true that the jacobian determinant of this transformation is $1$, if so why? I.e. does

$\int f(x)dx=\int f(y)dy$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $A$ is orthogonal, $\det(A) = \pm 1$. Why? By definition, $A A^T = I$, and taking determinant of both sides gives 
$$\det(A)^2 = \det(A)\det(A^T) = \det(A A^T) = \det(I) = 1. $$

Now as the change of coordinates $y = \phi(x) = Ax$ is linear, its derivative $(D\phi)(x)$ equals $A$. By change of variables,
$$\int f(y) dy = \int f(Ax)\, |\det (D\phi)(x)| dx = \int f(Ax)\, |\det A| dx = \int f(Ax) dx. $$

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you!

Comment: should you use $A^{-1}$? $y=Ax$, $\int f(y)dy=\int f(A^{-1}y)|\det(D\phi^{-1})(y)|dx=\int f(x)|det(A^{-1})|=\int f(x)dx$

Comment: If we’re writing $y = Ax$, then we have to write $f(y) = f(Ax)$ and so forth